# wp_handle_upload - "File is Empty" error

Tags: php, wordpress, email, xampp

Using XAMPP to develop a Wordpress website, this is occurring in a price match form I am writing. The user needs to be able to upload an image. Here is the upload part of the code (after validation)

**Error outputted:** "File is empty. Please upload something more substantial. This error could also be caused by uploads being disabled in your php.ini or by post_max_size being defined as smaller than upload_max_filesize in php.ini."

**Upload code from functions.php**

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
}

$uploadedfile = $_FILES["fileToUpload"];

$upload_overrides = array(
    'test_form' => false
);

$movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );

if ( $movefile && ! isset( $movefile['error'] ) ) {
//echo __( 'File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.', 'textdomain' ) . "\n";
var_dump( $movefile );
} else {
/*
* Error generated by _wp_handle_upload()
* @see _wp_handle_upload() in wp-admin/includes/file.php
*/
$fileErr = $movefile['error'];
}
```

- My wp-content folder permissions are set 755
- I've already ran phpinfo() to make sure that I am linking to the
  right php.ini file.

**In my php.ini file:**

- file_uploads=on
- memory_limit=128M
- upload_max_file_size=25M
- post_max_size=25M

I know this question has been asked by a bunch of people, and believe me I have been looking at all of the responses and trying everything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you physically checked that the file isn't actually uploaded to the server? WP sometimes does odd double loops that mean an uploaded file *might* appear to be missing on the page reload. I'd check this out just to eliminate this possibility.

Comment: Hey, dumb question, but where is the temp folder again for these files so i can check? @PhillHealey

Comment: What do you mean? What temp folder? For what?

Comment: Have you looked in the WordPress Media Library to see if the images are shown? If so, then they are being uplodaded. If not, there is definitely an issue.

Comment: Oh. Whoops I was thinking that wp_handle_upload stored uploaded files in a temporary location for handling. Unfortunately no, the images are not shown in the media library. @PhillHealey

Comment: Your code appears to be lifted straight from the codex, so assuming you've followed all the details there, then it should be working. Are you sure you have your files permission set appropriately?

Comment: I will check again, what would you recommend permissions wise? As of right now I had previously checked to make sure the permissions on the wp-content folder are 755, but it's possible I misread. Do you think this issue will still occur when the site goes live instead of hosted on localhost? @PhillHealey

Comment: You also need to make sure that the correct user:group has access to the files. As for whether this might happen on live hosting.... Who knows, it depends whether the environment is setup properly and if your code is correct or not.